# Android 2.3 Keyboard on SE X8 running 2.1

Tags: keyboard

Recently I've found out that it's possible to install new Android keyboard on 2.2 version of Android (here's the [installer](http://rapidshare.com/files/435722501/signedkey.apk)).

I was wondering if the same applies for 2.1?

I own SE X8 which I've recently updated to 2.1.

Comment: I've read that it only works on 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2.3 keyboard cannot be installed on 2.1 as-is.  It relies on the 2.3 Voice Search app, which uses API methods not present in 2.1.  (See [this XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9775478&postcount=2).)  I'm sure someone is in the process of hacking the keyboard to work though.  To be honest, the only difference I see with the 2.3 keyboard is that the keys are smaller, which I dislike.